# Dialog box buttons not visible on smaller screens and resolutions?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to show a tutorial when user runs the app for the first time, by using dialog boxes. However, the "back" and "next" buttons aren't visible on smaller screens and/or resolutions, so the user can't proceed with the tutorial.
I tried making the dialog box a ScrollView but it didn't help, buttons are still invisible. What's the best way to resolve this? Thanks in advance!
EDIT: here's an example of the first dialog shown to user:

```
AlertDialog.Builder w1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater w1Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View w1Layout = w1Inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) w1Layout.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    w1.setView(w1Layout);
    w1.setTitle("Welcome");
    w1.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Before you start using the app, get familiar with the User Interface!"));
    w1.setCancelable(false);
    w1.setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch3();
            num = 3;
            ((ViewGroup)w1Layout.getParent()).removeView(w1Layout);
        }
    });
```

And here's the dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/my_image"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Making your UI work for different screen sizes means following a few best practices - you can learn about your options here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support But as far as dialogs go, someone's already done that work for you! https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#DialogFragment Just use an `AlertDialog` like in that example - if you scroll down they show you how to add custom content too, but you can still add the standard buttons. But if your buttons are inside the content (like arrows at the edges) then you'll need a layout that can adapt

Comment: oh you're already using one - might want to add your dialog layout XML and a pic of what it looks like on big and small screens too

Comment: @cactustictacs Alright, I just added the xml code too

Comment: @cactustictacs I tried using TextView instead of setMessage(), and added textView inside dialog.xml and that seems to fix the problem. I'm wondering if there's a better way though

Comment: Yeah there's a little diagram here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#AlertDialog basically the title is at the top, the buttons are at the bottom, and the middle bit is the *content area*. `setMessage` is a quick way to get a dialog with a `TextView` in the content area, but if you're setting your own layout in there, you can't have both. It shouldn't break though (I'd expect to see the last thing you added) but hey. You might want to try `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` instead: https://material.io/components/dialogs/android#alert-dialog themed and might behave better?

Comment: @Cannon190 create a custom layout for small devices.